# Cracking a sha256 hash and i know how it will be like

Tags: encryption, cryptography, sha256

I have a sha256 hash and i know that it consists on numbers and small characters and the length is 64 so is there any way to crack it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on [crypto.se].

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 is a one-way **hash**, rather than an encryption. As such, you can't decrypt it. You **can**, however, bruteforce it.

MD5Decrypt has already covered more than 3 billion possible SHA256 strings, so there's a good chance you can find it [**here**](http://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha256/). Otherwise, you'll just need to try every possible combination there is, using what you already know.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: If it's 64 numbers + small letters, that's about 2^229, which is not feasibly brute-forceable.

Comment: Exactly. That's why it's a secure algorithm ;) But the OP does say that he knows *some* of the target string, meaning that you can eliminate at least some of the entropy. Depending on exactly **how** much entropy you can eliminate, you could bring the cracking time down significantly.

Comment: Going from 100 times the age of the universe down to 10 times the age of the universe is definitely a significant reduction in cracking time.  That doesn't mean it helps in the slightest though.